# Log4j levels not working as expected

Tags: logging, log4j2

I'm added log4j to my project so I can debbug it properly. But when i set log level to INFO or higher, it keeps showing debug level logs. Here the part of the class where I created the logger:

```
public abstract class DefaultDaoImpl<T> implements DefaultDao<T> {

private EntityManager em;
private Class<T> classeEntidade;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DefaultDaoImpl.class);

public DefaultDaoImpl(Class<T> classeEntidade) {
    this.classeEntidade = classeEntidade;
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
}
```

Here's a part of the log generated:

```
2847 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl  - Releasing JDBC connection
2847 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl  - Releasing JDBC connection
2847 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl  - Released JDBC connection
2847 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl  - Released JDBC connection
2847 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl  - Released JDBC connection
2847 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl  - Released JDBC connection
```

Note: debug logs came from hibernate. Maybe it's a hibernate config?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you configure log4j2 with a configuration file and specify the desired level in that configuration file. For anything else you are depending on implementation details and your code may break when you upgrade to a newer version of log4j2.

That said, take a look at the user manual page on [Manual Configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#AddingToCurrent). A key take-away is that you need to call the `LoggerContext.updateLoggers()` method after programmatically modifying the configuration.